# Why won't my function return largest even if numbers are negative

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to create a function that returns the largest even number in a list. I created this but it doesn't work for negative numbers and I'm not sure why.

```
def largest_even(list_int):
large = False
print(list_int)
for i in list_int:
    if i % 2 == 0:
        i = large
for i in list_int:
    if i % 2 == 0:
        if i > large:
            large = i
return large
```

Comment: `max(x for x in list_int if x % 2 == 0)`

Comment: First fix your indentation, then explain what doesn't work...

Comment: @dcg I would say that should be an answer, since it's not suggesting an improvement to the question... but it doesn't really answer the question of why the OP's code doesn't work, either.

Comment: Because you initialize `large` to `False` which is evaluated as `0` when used in the comparison. And btw, your first block doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

According to the comments above you can solve the problem with:

```
max(x for x in list_int if x % 2 == 0)
```

Your code must be modified as follows so it can get the largest even number in the passed list:

1- You need to fix the indentation in your code (I would guess it's due to copy and paste)

2- You can find the largest as:

```
large = None 
for x in list_int:
     if x % 2 == 0:
         if large is None: 
             large = x
         if x > large:
             large = x
```

Comment: `if not large` is True if `large == 0`. I suggest `if large is None` instead

Answer (score 0):

Why are you initializing large with False? I think you don't need to do that.
and the second error is at sixth line (i = large). it should be (large = i), as you want to store the first occurring even number to a variable and not the variable at that position in list.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for largest even, then **dcg**'s answer is right

If you're asking why your code doesn't work:

- First, it looks like you have nested `for`, so don't reuse same variable `i` inside nested loop unless you have a good reason to
- Second, this `i = large` should be `large = i`

Rewrite:

```
def largest_even(list_int):
    large = False
    for i in list_int:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            large = i
        for j in list_int:
            if j % 2 == 0:
                if j > large:
                    large = j
    return large
```

Answer (score 0):

One of your issues is that you're setting `i` to `False`, and then attempting to check if your current number is greater than `False`, which is not giving you the desired input. Instead, try the following one-liner:

```
def largest_even(list_int):
    return max([i for i in list_int if not i%2])
```

---

```
>>> largest_even([1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 333, 4])
4
>>> largest_even([1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 332, 4])
332
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just one line is wrong. It should have been large = i. Rest of the code perfectly fine

```
def largest_even(list_int):
    large = False
    print(list_int)
    for i in list_int:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            large = i
    for i in list_int:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            if i > large:
                large = i
    return large
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is working fine. I suppose you want to print the largest even number, even if it is negative. In that case you should use abs() function.
And also you are using for loop two times which I suppose is of no use. Below is the code, which works for given largest even number even if it is negative.

```
def largest_even(list_int):
    large = 0
    print(list_int)
    for i in list_int:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            if abs(i) > abs(large):
                large = i
    return large

print(largest_even([1,2,3,1,5,-10]))
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 5, -10]
-10
```